# Created arrays in PHP 5.6 with [] work, but in PHP 7.1 give fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.6, php-7.1

In PHP 5.6 this works fine, but in PHP 7.1 it gives Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings

```
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($id, $name);   
while($result->fetch()){
    $datos[]=array(
        $id => $name
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of PHP 7.1, when you access a non-array variable (in this case a string) like an array, a fatal error will be thrown.

Initialize the array first, with `$datos = [];`. This will overwrite anything you have set earlier, and explicitly set this variable as an array:

```
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($id, $name);
$datos = [];
while($result->fetch()){
    $datos[]=array(
        $id => $name
    );
}
```

If you're trying to create an array of `$id` => `$name`, the following code should work:

```
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($id, $name);
$datos = [];
while($result->fetch()){
    $datos[ $id ] = $name;
}
```

Comment: afaik, it shouldn't give a fatal error because the variable isn't defined when you're trying to write to it?  PHP should create that variable on the go, without saying anything. However, imho, you should define it, just like this answer suggests. @DeshBourne - Have you defined that variable `$datos` as a string before this code snippet? That would throw the fatal error you're getting, though.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Seems like a common variable name, and most likely was used as a string before.

Comment: It must be, or that specific error wouldn't appear :-) @DeshBourne - Suggestion: don't reuse variable names. That can lead to all sorts of issues (like this) and can make your code harder to debug.

Comment: It's a 7.1 "feature", `As of PHP 7.1.0, applying the empty index operator on a string throws a fatal error. Formerly, the string was silently converted to an array.`